# MySQL Vertical Join Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I've got the following tables: **users**, **attributes**, **attribute_values**, **user_attribute_values**.

Don't ask why I chose to structure the tables like this, I'm just trying to learn SQL (MySQL to be more specific) by playing with different ideas.

Table structure is as follows:

```
users
+--+
|id|
+--+
| 1|
+--+

attributes
+--+---------+
|id|attribute|
+--+---------+
| 1|name     |
+--+---------+
| 2|age      |
+--+---------+

attribute_values
+--+---------------+
|id|attribute_value|
+--+---------------+
| 1|John Doe       |
+--+---------------+
| 2|30             |
+--+---------------+

user_attribute_values
+-------+------------+------------------+
|user_id|attribute_id|attribute_value_id|
+-------+------------+------------------+
|      1|           1|                 1|
+-------+------------+------------------+
|      1|           2|                 2|
+-------+------------+------------------+
```

I am trying to figure out a query that will result in something like this:

```
+-------+---------+---------------+
|user_id|attribute|attribute_value|
+-------+---------+---------------+
|      1|name     |John Doe       |
+-------+---------+---------------+
|      1|age      |30             |
+-------+---------+---------------+
```

Or better yet, something like this:

```
+--+--------+---+
|id|    name|age|
+-----------+---+
| 1|John Doe|30 |
+-------+-------+
```

Bear in mind that the proper keys and foreign keys have been added to all tables.

The closest I could get was something like this:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `attributes`.`attribute`, `attribute_values`.`attribute_value`
FROM `users`, `attributes`, `attribute_values`, `user_attribute_values`
WHERE `users`.`id` = `user_attribute_values`.`user_id` AND `user_attribute_values`.`attribute_id` = 1 AND `user_attribute_values`.`attribute_value_id` = 1;
```

Which results in:

```
+--+---------+---------------+
|id|attribute|attribute_value|
+--+---------+---------------+
| 1|     name|John Doe       |
+--+---------+---------------+
| 1|      age|John Doe       |
+--+---------+---------------+
| 1|     name|30             |
+--+---------+---------------+
| 1|      age|27             |
+--+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Proper joins should probably fix your problem:

```
SELECT u.id, a.attribute, av.attribute_value
FROM users u JOIN
     user_attribute_values uav
     ON u.id = uav.user_id JOIN
     attributes a
     ON uav.attribute_id = a.id JOIN
     attribute_values av 
     ON uav.attribute_value_id = av.attribute_value_id
WHERE av.id = 1 AND a.id = 1;
```

I'm not sure what the `WHERE` clause is supposed to be doing.  I assume you really want `WHERE u.id = 1` based on the sample results.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will mark this as the answer. Is it possible to construct a query that would result in the second form? Meaning total conversion from vertical to horizontal?

Comment: @xandrw . . . Not easily.  That requires dynamic SQL.  A SQL query must explicitly list the columns being returned, and for that version the columns are in the data rather than being constant.